# Is It Ok To Use Another Name For EFI Partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So, long story short... I managed to install Ubuntu 17.10, MacOSX and Phoenix OS on my MacBook Pro mid-2010 (for my blog). But I'm having difficulties recognizing which partitions I'm using for which OS.So I'm planning to make a clean install and renaming the partitions accordingly, eg. EFIUBUNTU etc.
Is that possible? Thank's.

Comment: You should be having only one EFI partition. How many do you have?

Comment: You should just need to boot each OS and check what partitions they mount. Does that not work?

Comment: If it is just the label, it should be ok. UEFI actually uses a very long GUID to identify the ESP. But partition tools use different methods to assign that GUID code. See partition type GUID section about half way down. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table  But you only want one ESP per device, as noted by others below. To see parttype: `lsblk -o +parttype`

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible though not desirable* to have multiple EFI partitions on one single system, but you'd have to manually maintain them as any other system will only have one EFI system partition except yours and mine (I have a back-up copy of my EFI partition on my secondary hard disk, but have removed some of the flags and changed the UID so that it does not come up as an EFI partition.)

So:

#### Yes, it's possible...

## No, it's a bad idea!

(Sorry!)